# Pandas Group Columns by Value of 1 and Sort By Frequency

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I have to take this dataframe:

```
d = {'Apple': [0,0,1,0,1,0], 'Aurora': [0,0,0,0,0,1], 'Barn': [0,1,1,0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

  Apple Aurora Barn
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1
2   1   0   1
3   0   0   0
4   1   0   0
5   0   1   0
```

And count the frequency of the number one in each column, and create a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Apple',0.3333], ['Aurora',0.166666], ['Barn', 0.3333]], columns = ['index', 'value'])

    index   value
0   Apple   0.333300
1   Aurora  0.166666
2   Barn    0.333300
```

I have tried this:

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby(1)[1].transform('count')
```

But I get an error: `KeyError: 1`

So I'm not sure how to count the value 1 across rows and columns, and group by column names and the frequency of 1 in each column.

Comment: Try this: `df.mean()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could do simply this:

```
freq = df.mean()
```

Output:

```
>>> freq
Apple     0.333333
Aurora    0.166667
Barn      0.333333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. It works!

Comment: Yes, it is very simple. I know the feeling :)

Comment: Haha, too true !